# Can Subclipse's recent branch list be extended beyond 5 entries?

Tags: eclipse, svn, branch, subclipse

I use Subclipse frequently to switch between many branches, perhaps 10-15 at a time. (Yes, I'm aware this is a lot.)

The To URL field provides a helpful dropdown of the 5 most recent branches. Would be great if this could be extended to show more. Is it configurable?

[Screenshot http://desktop-eclipse.open.collab.net/images/switch-multi.png](http://desktop-eclipse.open.collab.net/images/switch-multi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is not a preference or anything, so you would need to file an enhancement request with the Subclipse project - http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=t65B1R

You might also take a look at the branch/tag UI feature:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/branch_tag.html

This lets you "register" your branches in SVN properties which then exists as a UI shortcut in the Select dialog.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for confirming!